# Getting the manifest list (fat manifest) from docker registry

Tags: docker

While using the docker registry API, I was trying to access the manifest list (aka fat manifest) as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/manifest-v2-2/).

The details of the curl call are:

```
curl "https://myserver/v2/<repository>/manifests/<version/" -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json"
```

However the response for this is with the schemaVersion of 1. An Accept header of `application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json` does seem to get the correct version of the manifest but doesn't seem to be working for the list type accept header.

Am I missing something in the URL or the headers?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json` header. There is however no guarantee that the registry serves you a manifest list, so you have to be able to handle ordinary image manifests as well.

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/manifest-v2-2/):

> When pulling images, clients indicate support for this new version of
>   the manifest format by sending the
>   `application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json` and
>   `application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json` media types
>   in an Accept header when making a request to the manifests endpoint.
>   Updated clients should check the Content-Type header to see whether
>   the manifest returned from the endpoint is in the old format, or is an
>   image manifest or manifest list in the new format.